# How to properly grow label automatically according to text's size?

Tags: winapi, label, autosize

I did create a new rectangle in the `WM_PAINT` but in order to change the text, I also [`SetWindowText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtextw), I need a [`InvalidateRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) so it seems quite hacky to me. What's the proper way to do that? I'm not sure if I'm calculating the proper height and width properly either. I've tried grow using [`SetWindowPos()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) from WM_PAINT but it failed so I switch to draw it using [`Rectangle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-rectangle). I did that because I wanted the text o vertical center but static control doesn't support that, so I went to do the paiting myself so I can use [`DrawText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext) with `DT_CENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER` flags. Here's how I'm handling `VM_PAINT`:

```
case WM_PAINT:
        { 
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            RECT rt = {0};
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rt);
            
            int height = rt.right - rt.left;
            int width = rt.bottom - rt.top;
            int len = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);
            wchar_t s[len+1];
            GetWindowText(hwnd, s, len+1);
            int flags = DT_CENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER;
            HDC dc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            
            // calculate the width and height
            DrawText(dc, s, -1, &rt, DT_CALCRECT | flags);
            width += rt.right;
            height += rt.bottom;
            
            // update width and height
            rt.right = width;
            rt.bottom = height;

            Rectangle(dc, rt.left, rt.top, rt.right, rt.bottom);

            // this prevent from painting the border. 
            InflateRect(&rt, -1, -1);
            FillRect(dc, &rt, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BTNFACE));
            SetBkMode(dc, TRANSPARENT);
            DrawText(dc, s, -1, &rt, flags);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        }
```

full code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdi32.lib")

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

#include <windows.h>
#include <Commctrl.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

WNDPROC oldButtonProc;
HINSTANCE ghInstance;
HWND hTab;
HFONT hdDfaultFont;
HWND btn;

enum 
{
    BTN_ID = 10,
    BTN2_ID,
};


int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    MSG  msg = {0};
    HWND hwnd;
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};

    wc.lpszClassName = L"Window";
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    
    //InitComControls();
    if(!RegisterClass(&wc)) {
        return -1;
    }

    int width = 540;
    int height = 460;
    int screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    int cx = (screenWidth - width) / 2;
    int cy = (screenHeight - height) / 2;
    hwnd = CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Window",
                        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                        cx, cy, width, height, NULL, NULL, 
                        hInstance, NULL);
    ghInstance = hInstance;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!IsDialogMessage(hwnd, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    DeleteObject(hdDfaultFont);
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

  switch(msg)
  {
      case WM_CREATE:
      {
            btn =
            CreateWindow(L"static", L"init text",
                SS_NOTIFY |
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
                0, 0, 20, 30,
                hwnd, (HMENU) BTN_ID, NULL, NULL);
            oldButtonProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLongPtr(btn,
                                        GWLP_WNDPROC,
                                        (LONG_PTR) ButtonProc);
            HWND btn2 =
            CreateWindow(L"Button", L"Click me!",
                        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
                        10, 50, 70, 25, 
                        hwnd, (HMENU) BTN2_ID,
                        NULL, NULL);
            SetDefaultFont(btn2);
      }
      break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            case BTN2_ID:
            {
                SetWindowText(btn, L"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa0");
                InvalidateRect(btn, NULL, TRUE);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    break;    
    
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
  }

  return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
        { 
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            RECT rt = {0};
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rt);
            
            int height = rt.right - rt.left;
            int width = rt.bottom - rt.top;
            
            int len = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);
            wchar_t s[len+1];
            GetWindowText(hwnd, s, len+1);

            int flags = DT_CENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER;
            HDC dc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            
            // calculate the width and height
            DrawText(dc, s, -1, &rt, DT_CALCRECT | flags);
            width += rt.right;
            height += rt.bottom;
            
            // update width and height
            rt.right = width;
            rt.bottom = height;
            Rectangle(dc, rt.left, rt.top, rt.right, rt.bottom);
            InflateRect(&rt, -1, -1);
            FillRect(dc, &rt, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BTNFACE));
            SetBkMode(dc, TRANSPARENT);
            DrawText(dc, s, -1, &rt, flags);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    }

    return CallWindowProc(oldButtonProc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GetTextExtentPoint32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-gettextextentpoint32w) to find the string length and then you don't need to do calculations.

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rt = { 0 };
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rt);
    int len = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);
    wchar_t s[len + 1];
    GetWindowText(hwnd, s, len + 1);
    int flags = DT_CENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER;
    HDC dc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    SIZE sz;
    GetTextExtentPoint32(dc, s, len, &sz);
    rt.right = sz.cx + 10;  //I added 10 to make the display less crowded.
    rt.bottom = sz.cy;

    Rectangle(dc, rt.left, rt.top, rt.right, rt.bottom);

    // this prevent from painting the border. 
    InflateRect(&rt, -1, -1);
    FillRect(dc, &rt, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BTNFACE));
    SetBkMode(dc, TRANSPARENT);
    DrawText(dc, s, -1, &rt, flags);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the `X` part of the `XY` problem, `DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE` implies single-line text, and in that case a static control with the [`SS_CENTERIMAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/static-control-styles) style will center the text vertically.

> `SS_CENTERIMAGE` -
> *A bitmap is centered in the static control that contains it. The control is not resized, so that a bitmap too large for the control will be clipped.* ***If the static control contains a single line of text, the text is centered vertically in the client area of the control.***